# SPD: Kbd shortcut to move focus from Design view to Code view?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a file open for editing in Advanced Mode in SPD. I'm in the Design mode editor. How can I switch to the Code view editor using my keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on ALT + W + C to switch to code mode.

ALT + W + D = Design Mode

ALT + W + S = Split Mode

The Trick is to click on "ALT" and then see the shortcuts displayed in ribbon. If what you are looking to do is available in Ribbon, it will display the shortcuts.